# Валидация через Callback в Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

каким образом можно в анотациях корректно указать кастомную функцию валидации. вариант из доки не проходит

```
/**
 * @GQL\Field(type="String")
 * @Assert\Callback("validate")
 * @GQL\Description(value="template Image")
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $templateId;

public static function validate($object, ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
{
   dd($object);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
* @GQL\Field(type="String")
* @GQL\Description(value="template Image")
* @var string
*/
public $templateId;


/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
{
    if (!$this->templateId) {
        $context->buildViolation('templateId not valid')
            ->atPath('templateId')
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```